# How to iteratively add new columns to pre-existing numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a set of n points paired in x,y coordinates. I would like to, based on some exclusionary criteria (doesn't matter which one), store a pair of selected x,y points into a new array.

The points are stored in an array consisting of two rows (for x and y) and multiple columns (bunch of points). I've begun by initializing an empty array (let's call it "store") that has 2 rows and one column using numpy.empty([2,1]). Next up I've started an iteration in range of number of columns+1, putting x as [0,n] and y as [1,n] respectively - so that x is always the element of n-th column and first row while y is an element of of n-th column and second row. Then there is the exclusionary criteria (it doesn't matter much at this point). After that, I've defined a new array (let's call it "member") of one column and two rows (x,y). Then I defined a new array (let's call it "new") with numpy.append(store,member,1) (1 being so I can append columnwise. The code  then looks like this:

```
points=np.array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ])
store=np.empty([2,1])
```

This is my set of points and my targeted array store.

```
for i in range(n):
  x=points[0,i]
  y=points[1,i]
  member=np.array([ [x], [y] ])
  new=np.append(store,member,1)
```

And it doesn't quite work. Is there any better way?

Comment: `It doesn't quite work`?  do you mean it works, except for some small problem?  Or is there something fundamentally wrong?  Actual error, or just not the right result?  What did you expect?

Comment: I start with two row one column matrix and then it adds another column so I have two column matrix. But, then it instead of adding another column (so that there's three and them four etc) it simply rewrites the second column.

Comment: well duh!  Look at your loop.  Each time you append to the original `store`, not the `new`.  Contrary to list `append`, `np.append` does not work in-place.  It makes a new array each time.  It a big loop `np.append` is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way, you can avoid a for loop and use indexing.

```
import numpy as np

points=np.array([ [1,2,3], [2,3,4] ])
value = 2 

indx = points <= value #criterion
indx = np.logical_and(indx[0,:], indx[1,:]) #if the criterion applies to both x and y
store = points[:,indx] #get each column that matches the criterion
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: points=np.array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]) 
   ...: store=np.empty([2,1])                                                   
In [2]: store                                                                   
Out[2]: 
array([[7.74860419e-304],
       [7.74860419e-304]])
```

The values in the array produced by `np.empty` are arbitrary.

`np.append` with an axis value is just a variation on `np.concatenate`.  We could easily join `store` and `points`:

```
In [3]: np.concatenate([store, points], axis=1)                                 
Out[3]: 
array([[7.74860419e-304, 1.00000000e+000, 2.00000000e+000,
        3.00000000e+000],
       [7.74860419e-304, 4.00000000e+000, 5.00000000e+000,
        6.00000000e+000]])
```

Your `member` calc:

```
In [4]: i=0                                                                     
In [5]:   x=points[0,i] 
   ...:   y=points[1,i] 
   ...:   member=np.array([ [x], [y] ])                                         
In [6]: member                                                                  
Out[6]: 
array([[1],
       [4]])
In [7]: points[:,[i]]        # same thing, the ith column of points                                                   
Out[7]: 
array([[1],
       [4]])
```

You could add columns of `points` to a `store` array iteratively:

```
In [8]: store = np.ones([2,1],int)                                              
In [9]: store                                                                   
Out[9]: 
array([[1],
       [1]])
In [10]: store = np.concatenate([store, points[:,[0]]],1)                       
In [11]: store                                                                  
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 4]])
In [12]: store = np.concatenate([store, points[:,[1]]],1)                       
In [13]: store                                                                  
Out[13]: 
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [1, 4, 5]])
In [14]: store = np.concatenate([store, points[:,[2]]],1)                       
In [15]: store                                                                  
Out[15]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 4, 5, 6]])
```

But as a general rule  iterative work with numpy is slow.  Better to work with lists.

```
In [16]: store=[]            # empty list, no relation to np.empty                                                         
In [17]: for i in range(3): 
    ...:     store.append(points[:,i]) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [18]: store                                                                  
Out[18]: [array([1, 4]), array([2, 5]), array([3, 6])]
In [19]: np.array(store)                                                        
Out[19]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
In [20]: np.array(store).T                                                      
Out[20]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
points=np.array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ])
store=np.empty([2,1])

store=np.hstack((store, points))
```